# Max-Flow Min-Cut

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, linear-programming, network-flow

So I have worked out that there is a Max Flow of 10, which therefore means there is a minimum cut also of 10 however how do I draw a minimum cut of 10 on this image? (Something like this - [image](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=0ahUKEwjImuialsHMAhXrIcAKHWJzC3QQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gfgreader.info%2Fpost%2F551e0a4ffd1aae1373effdd4&psig=AFQjCNHRqsJaeUFcZ3Kq0CwNSvE0FdD-kQ&ust=1462477181969234))

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to come up with it.

Start with some $S \to T$ flow, e.g. the straight horizontal. Subtract min capacity from all edges (would be 2 here). Now you have a modified graph and are sending a flow of 2.

Repeat in the modified graph, until you are sending a flow of 10. At that point, there will not be possible to send any more flow.

In that graph, capture the cut, and unite the cuts from all steps together to get a 10-cut in the original graph.